# When I will change a class on Production (via change set deployment), then I need to delete and add "Scheduled Job"?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I changed a class via change sets deplyment.

Do I need to remove "Scheduled Job" with that class and add it again?

Answer (score 5):

It depends on if you [enable](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000323577&type=1) "Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress". When false, deployments will automatically fail if any jobs are pending. When true, deployments will not fail, but your code *may* crash if the state of the class has changed (e.g. adding/removing/changing class-level variables or methods). If you're unsure, it would be safer to unschedule, deploy, and reschedule afterwards.

Comment: does this mean changes that don't affect the state are always safe to deploy? Like, adding comments?

Comment: @SarcasticSully we're intentionally not told, but I would suggest that any change that does not materially affect a JSON.deserialize between two copies of the code should not fail. Including comments.